# Is there a cleaner solution for this conditional statement?

Tags: javascript

Is there a cleaner, more concise way to write the following conditional statement that creates a string in Javascript?

```
var search;

if (text === '' && user === '' && filter !== '') {
    search = filter;
} else if (filter === '' && text  === '' && user !== '') {
  search = 'email="' + user + '"';
} else if (filter === '' && user  === '' && text !== '') {
  search = 'text~"' + text  + '"';
} else if (text !== '' && user  !== '' && filter === '') {
    search = 'text~"' + text + '" ANDemail="' + user + '"';
} else if (text !== '' && filter  !== '' && user === '') {
    search = 'text~"' + text + '" AND ' + filter;
} else {
  search = 'text~"' + text + '" AND ' + filter + '" ANDemail="' + user + '"';
}
```

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is switching `text === ''` to `!text` or `filter !== ''` to `filter` only like this: `if (!text && !user && filter)`

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Answer (score 1):

// using computed switch

```
var TEXT = 1,   haveText = (text !== "") << 0;
var FILTER = 2, haveFilter = (filter !== "") << 1;
var USER = 4,   haveUser = (user !== "") << 2;

switch(haveText + haveFilter + haveUser)
{
case FILTER:  search = filter; break;
case USER:    search = 'email="' + user + '"'; break;
case TEXT: search = 'text~"' + text  + '"'; break;
case TEXT+USER: search = 'text~"' + text + '" AND email="' + user + '"'; break;
case TEXT+FILTER: search = 'text~"' + text + '" AND ' + filter; break;
case TEXT+FILTER+USER: search = 'text~"' + text + '" AND ' + filter + '" AND email="' + user + '"'; break;
case FILTER+USER: search = filter + '" AND email="' + user + '"'; break;
default: search = ""; // no search criteria
}
```

makes two possible errors in the compound if statement version stand out:

1. The case of FILTER+USER was not tested for and produced a search using TEXT,
2. The case of no criteria was not tested in the if statement and also produced a search using TEXT.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, one thing you can do to simplify this is to use the js rule that '' falsy which simplifies this. Also, short circuits with return would help.

```
var search;

function getSearch(user, text, filter) {
    if (!text && !user && filter) return filter;
    if (!filter && !text && user) return 'email="' + user + '"';
    if (!filter && !user && text ) return 'text~"' + text  + '"';
    if (text && user && !filter) return 'text~"' + text + '" ANDemail="' + user + '"';
    if (text && filter && !user) return 'text~"' + text + '" AND ' + filter;
    return 'text~"' + text + '" AND ' + filter + '" ANDemail="' + user + '"';
}

search = getSearch(user, text, filter);
```

I think that's a little cleaner. It could be cleaned up a lot if the formatting of your string wasn't so strange, but I'm assuming it's specific and required so this maintains the exact formatting you're after in the "search" string.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function to build the search string, that way you can easily add more variables in the future. The builder is messy, it's a messy process, but it won't get much more messy, no matter how many variables you add. As a side-note, remember that in some cases like this (with a lot of conditionals) you can consider refactoring using polymorphism, that probably wouldn't work for you here, though. The fiddle for this is here: https://jsfiddle.net/ytg1rxu8/

```
function buildSearchString(text, user, filter) {
var returnString = '';
var strings = [];
if (text) {strings.push('text~ =' + text);}
if (user) {strings.push('email = ' + user);}
if(filter){
    strings.push(filter);}
var length = strings.length;
for(var i =0; i < length; ++i){
    var s = strings[i];
    if(i ===length -1){
         returnString += s;              
    }
    else{
        returnString += s+' AND '  ;            
    }                                                    
}
return returnString;
}
alert(buildSearchString('', 'there', 'guy'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following may fit the criterion "concise", but it may not fit "cleaner":

```js
var text = 'someText';
var filter = '';
var user = 'aUser';

var search = text? 'text~"' + text + '"' : '';
search += search && filter? ' AND ' + filter : filter? filter : '';
search += search && user? ' AND email="' + user + '"' : user? 'email="' + user + '"' : '';

document.write('Search: ' + search); // text~"someText" AND email="aUser"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var search;

if (filter)
    search = appendFilter(search, filter);
if (text)
    search = appendFilter(search, 'text~"' + text  + '"');
if (user)
    search = appendFilter(search, 'email="' + user + '"');

function appendFilter(search, f) {
    return search ? search + ' AND ' + f : f;
}
```

Comment: If all parameters are empty strings then `search` will be `undefined`.

Comment: @zerkms so what. Didn't check if I copied the whole logic. The point is if you really need 15 comparisons to build the search string or merely 3, maybe 4.

Comment: The point is that if you take into account **all** the requirements (not just a subset that allows you to provide something that looks nice) - your implementation will be even worse than what we have in the question.

Comment: @zerkms I can live with that

Comment: You can indeed, you didn't answer the question though (since this suggestion does not improve anything)